# What does node stream mean?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm reading [the official Java article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html) about serialization and came across with the *node stream* concept. More percisely:

> The next step is to actually persist the object. That is done with the
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream class. That class is a filter stream--it is
>   wrapped around a lower-level byte stream (called a *node stream*) to
>   handle the serialization protocol for us.

I looked at the source code of `ObjectOutputStream` but didn't find any class or interface called `NodeStream`. The class looks as follows:

```
public class ObjectOutputStream
    extends OutputStream implements ObjectOutput, ObjectStreamConstants
```

Couldn't you explain it a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second entry from a google search gave me this:

**Node streams {Data sink stream}**

Contain the basic functionality of reading or writing from a specific location.

Types of node streams include files, memory and pipes.

**Filter streams {Processing stream}**

Layered onto node streams between threads or processes.

For additional functionality – altering or managing data in the stream.

Comment: Interesting... So, if the user want to write data somewhere they should use the FilterStreams and avoid using Node Streams directly, is that correct?

Comment: @St.Antario If you are dealing with **information** = **data with known meaning**, this is correct. If you just like to perform general data operations,  e.g. copying, calculating checksums, zipping, buffering, etc, then *node streams* (may) fit better.

Answer (score 1):

*node stream* is not the name of a class member of `ObjectOutputStream`, but it's rather a `Stream` instance, with which the class works internally.

From what I can see in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java), this is the `BlockDataOutputStream`, defined on line 175:

```
private final BlockDataOutputStream bout;
```

Comment: I expected to find some native methods with platform-specific implementation, but the only native methods in the class are converetes `floatsToBytes` and `doublesToBytes`

Comment: It seems I don't quite understand the responsibility of streams. I think of them as some wrappers on low-level functions for writing to files, sockets etc depending on the actual stream instance.

Comment: @St.Antario what you just described are *filter streams* - they are wrapped around *node streams* and operate with sequential **information** (don't care about how to write/read, but what to do with it). *node streams* are interfaces to operate with sequential **data** (don't care about what to do with it, but how to write/read).

Comment: @St.Antario probably the name *node stream* comes from the idea that there are streams of data between two "nodes", e.g. persistent memory (file system), volatile memory (RAM), computers (network sockets)