# What is the difference between a "node stream" and a "filter stream"?

Tags: java, java-io

I am having difficulty understanding the differences between "node streams" and "filter streams".

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042717/what-does-node-stream-mean) question.

> **Node streams {Data sink stream}**
>
> - Contain the basic functionality of reading or writing from a specific location.
> - Types of node streams include files, memory and pipes.
>
> **Filter streams {Processing stream}**
>
> - Layered onto node streams between threads or processes.
> - For additional functionality – altering or managing data in the stream.

Can anyone provide some examples to explain the differences more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Node is more like nodeJS while filter is just String function filtering out texts.

Answer (score 0):

**Node Stream:**

In Java, a "node stream" is often referred to as a "low-level" or "basic" stream. These are the fundamental streams that directly interact with a data source or destination, such as a file or network connection.
Examples of node streams include **FileInputStream** and **FileOutputStream** for reading from and writing to files, respectively.
**Filter Stream:**

A "filter stream" (or "decorator stream") is a stream that adds some functionality to an existing node stream. It allows you to perform additional processing on the data being read or written.

---

Examples of filter streams include **BufferedInputStream** and **BufferedOutputStream**, which add buffering capabilities to an existing input or output stream.